# wpf Nested Datagrid not Populating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, nested

I am having problems populating a nested data grid in wpf when using a view model:

I have two classes:  CompensationEvent and Compensation Event Correspondence.  CompensationEvent contains a property of List Correspondence. (I know that in the code i have spelt Correspondence wrong - this isn't the issue though)

I want my main data grid to populate the ComppensationEvents, and the nested grid to populate the correspondence for the SelectedCompensationEvent property.

Here is my xaml (showing only relevant sections):

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="objDataGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCompensationEvent}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CompensationEvents}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Project" Binding="{Binding Path=Project}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Commments" Binding="{Binding Path=Comment}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Raised" Binding="{Binding Path=DateRaised}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid Height ="100" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedCompensationEvent.Correspondance}" CanUserAddRows="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Correspondance Type"  Binding="{Binding Path=CorrespondanceTypeID.Heading}" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header ="Issued By" Binding="{Binding Path=CorrespondanceTypeID.IssuedBy.PartyName}" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header ="Date Issued" Binding="{Binding Path=DateIssued}" Width="*"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Margin="5" Grid.Row ="4" Height ="100" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedCompensationEvent.Correspondance}" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Correspondance Type"  Binding="{Binding Path=CorrespondanceTypeID.Heading}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header ="Issued By" Binding="{Binding Path=CorrespondanceTypeID.IssuedBy.PartyName}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header ="Date Issued" Binding="{Binding Path=DateIssued}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

As you can see I have two grids and a nested grid in the row details template.  The second grid (at the end of the code) and the nested grid are defined exactly the same.

When I run my application and populate the CompensationEvents property, the first (outer) grid populates fine, happy with that.

When I select a row in the outer grid, thus populating SelectedCompensationEvent, the lower grid populates with all the correspondence so I know my view model is working.  However the nested grid remains stubbornly empty.

The only thing I can think of is that the nested grid is drawn before the SelectedCompensationEvent is populated on selecting a row - could that be right?

Anyway, any answers would be appreciated

Thanks in advance - Mick

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code, my guess would be that the inner grid is not populating because it's not binding to what you think it is. If you open the output window while debugging the program do you see any binding errors? It should say something like: *BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedCompensationEvent.Correspondance' property not found on 'object' ...*

If this is the case, you'll need to tell the nested grid to bind explicitly to the object in the data context. This link may be able to help, if you're unsure of how to do that: http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/sloscialo/where-s-my-datacontext